# What do different fill (background) colors mean in the MLB schedule?

Tags: baseball

In [the schedule](https://www.mlb.com/redsox/schedule/2020-08), MLB official site displays games in different fill (background) colors. For instance, the Red Sox vs. Yankees game on July 31 is in grey fill color, while the game on July 7 is in white.

What does the coloring mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't copy the important part of the table, because it's stated below what each color stands for.

[image]

To be honest, this isn't entirely true, because the white color is only for completed *home* games to distinguish between completed home and away games.

- Sapphire = upcoming home games
- Grey = *all* away games
- White = completed home games

You can as well see this by the annotations in each field (*vs.* for home and *@* for away). It's a perfect match.

Comment: Thank you. Does `field` in "by the annotations in each field" mean `baseball field`, like Fenway Park?

Comment: @JJJohn no, I was referring to the table fields (days) of the calendar.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the reason home games have two colorations (completed / upcoming) and away games one, is that the main purpose they're hoping people use this schedule for is shopping for tickets.